# How can I optimize this code?

Tags: php, optimization, validation

How do I optimize the following PHP code?

```
<?php

if(strlen($_POST['myName']) < 2 || isNumeric($_POST['myName']))
{
    echo "Please fill in your name!";
    exit();
}

if(!is_numeric($_POST['myAge']) || strlen($_POST['myAge'] < 1))
{
    echo "Please enter only digits!";
    exit();
}

if(strlen($_POST['myRes']) < 2 || isNumeric($_POST['myRes']))
{
    echo "Please enter something!";
    exit();
}

echo "Hi " . $_POST['myName'] . "! you are " . $_POST['myAge'] . " years old and live in " . $_POST['myRes'] . "? Nice to meet you!";

?>
```

What if I wanted to test, lets say, 100 inputs - how would I do it in the best way?

Comment: Isn't this akin to "How do I optimize 'Hello world'"?

Comment: No homework! Just wondering, i heard that using singlequotes would be faster than using doublequotes when echo? Is that true? And the same for strlen, instead of strlen using isset!

Comment: If your web site is running slowly, I can pretty much guarantee that these lines of code are not your problem.

Comment: No my website isn't running slowly, i just wanted to learn how to optimize code and maybe write it easier if it is possible.

Comment: @EricP - When using single quotes, the string isn't parsed for variables and whatnot, but this script is so simple you'll not see any performance gain.  This script is going to be about as fast as a script can be.  No optimization needed.

Comment: Okey, thank you all for the fast reply. So basically there is no need for optimizing small codes like this. But what if i wanted to test lets say 100 inputs, how would i do it the best way?

Comment: Use a validation framework - that'll most likely have code optimised for performance *and* readability.

Comment: btw, Eric, don't forget that you can (and should) edit your question rather than commenting - I've just improved the title (I think some people saw that as rude) and added your additional question regarding 100 inputs - but if you have any more thoughts then look for the edit link under the tags to add them yourself.

Comment: What's up with down/closevotes? Since when is learning objectionable here?

Comment: @stereofrog he won't learn anything here anyway. just ridiculous advises like "use interpolation instead of concatenation". he's better to learn somewhere else

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, if I dare to say, OP (and maybe others) can learn quite a lot from my answer. If you disagree, feel free to post your own, better, version.

Comment: Its always worth learning and doing it here is fine.

Comment: @EricP: You'd have been better off adding the contents of your first comment (above) into the question, that way people would have a better idea of what you were actually asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know about speed, but from the style point of view your code can be improved like this (one of many possible ways of course).

```
function p($key) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? trim($_POST[$key]) : null;
}

$name = p('myName');
$age  = intval(p('myAge'));
$res  = p('myRes');

$err  = array();

if(!preg_match('~^\w{3,}+$~', $name))
    $err[] = "Please fill in your name!";

if($age < 3 || $age > 99)
    $err[] = "Please enter a valid age";

if(!preg_match('~^\w{3,}+$~', $res))
    $err[] = "Please fill in your location!";

if($err)
    echo implode("<br>", $err);
else
    echo "Hi $name! you are $age years old and live in $res? Nice to meet you!";
```

Note the important points

- avoid direct access to superglobals like $_POST all over the code
- use regular expressions to validate strings
- force integer conversion when expecting a number
- avoid exit()
- use string interpolation instead of concatenation

Comment: Your `\w` will allow numeric names. Also, do you mean "...when *accepting* a number"?

Answer (score 1):

Well.. In fact you should add check for `isset()` before using any of the $_POST variables, and you can change `strlen($_POST['myAge'] < 1)` (notice you have your `)` in wrong place) to `empty($_POST['myAge'])`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do form validation try this out http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21
It's client side so you'd still want some sort of server side validation, but this always makes it easier on me

Comment: jQuery might be the best thing in the world, but **your response has nothing at all to do with PHP validation nor optimising the code posted** so it should not be posted here as an answer.

Comment: I always hate it when this happens. I love the community here and wanted to start contributing, but then someone is a complete jerk to me. I understand that my answer is not a direct answer to his question, but it provides another tool he may be able to use to help him. My comment may help him at some point in his coding career, even if it doesn't help him right this very instant. Your comment just discourages me from wanting to try and help others, and 100% does nothing to help the asker with anything.